# go-swagger - array of objects in request body

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I'm using [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger) for generating swagger file for our APIs
I've been trying to add comments for an API that gets an array of objects in request but the go-swagger seems like is not recognizing it

my request looks like this in JSON format:

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "title1",
      "label": "tag1",
      "sort": true
    },
    {
      "name": "title2",
      "label": "tag2",
      "sort": true
    }
  ]
}
```

this is what my comments looks like right now

```
// swagger:route POST /admin/qc QC createQC
//
// Creates a new QC.
//
//
//     Consumes:
//     - application/json
//
//     Produces:
//     - application/json
//
//     Schemes: https
//
//     Deprecated: false
//
//
//     Parameters:
//       + name: Authorization
//         in: header
//         required: true
//         type: string
//
//       + name: input
//         in: body
//         required: true
//         type: array
//         items: QC
//
//     Responses:
//       200: StatusOK
```

this is the generated swagger file

```
/admin/qc:
    post:
      consumes:
      - application/json
      operationId: createQC
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        required: true
        type: string
      - in: body
        name: input
        required: true
        schema:
          type: array
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        "200":
          description: StatusOK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/StatusOK'
      schemes:
      - https
      summary: Creates a new QC.
      tags:
      - QC
```

the go-swagger does not pick up the items type in this annotation.
the option to change the request type of this API is not available unfortunately.

anybody has any idea how I should annotate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to annotate this type of request you will need to define a new struct like this:

```
// swagger:parameters createQC
type CreateQCReqs struct {
    // in: body
    Body []*CreateQCReq
}
```

you need to annotate this with `swagger:parameters` followed by operation id of the api
after that you need to define `Body` field with your desired data type
in my case it was an array of `CreateQCReq`
after that you need to remove the body parameter in your `swagger:route`, otherwise the body field in your swagger file will be generated 2 times